# how to check if an element equals to specific index of multidimensional list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have two multidimensional list I have to check if the element is in the multidimensional list My code is:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
import numpy as np
import os
root= tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()
filepath =filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes = (("trace files","*.trace"),("out files",".out")))
file=open(filepath)
file_path = file.name
ext= os.path.splitext(file_path)
readData=file.readlines()
list1=[]
list2=[]
pht=[[1,0]]
goodPred=0
badPred=0
count=0

for read in readData:
    split= read.split(' ')
    addr =split[0]
    action= split[1]
    list1.append([addr,action.strip()])


    # if(len(pht)>500):
    #     del pht[0]
for i in range(len(list1)):


    if list1[i][0] in pht ##how to check from index 1 of pht for eg:pht[##what to mention here##][1]##:

        list2_index = list2.index(list1[i][0])
        print(list2_index)
    else:
        # print(list1[i][0])
        list2.append(list1[i][0])
```

My list1 is as follows:

```
[['3086703274', 'T'], ['3086703274', 'T'], ['3086703274', 'T'], ['3086703274', 'T'], ['3086703274', 'T'], ['3086703274', 'T'], ['3086703274', 'T'], ['3086703274', 'T'], ['3086703274', 'T'], ['3086703274', 'T'], ['3086703274', 'T'], ['3086703274', 'T'], ['3086703274', 'T'], ['3086703274', 'T'], ['3086703274', 'T'], ['3086703274', 'T'], ['3086703274', 'T'], ['3086703274', 'T'], ['3086703274', 'T'], ['3086703274', 'T'], ['3086703274', 'T'], ['3086703274', 'T'], ['3086703274', 'T'], ['3086703274', 'T'], ['3086703274', 'T'], ['3086703274', 'T'], ['3086703274', 'T'], ['3086703274', 'T'], ['3086703274', 'T'], ['3086703274', 'T'], ['3086703274', 'T']]
```

My Pht is as follows for eg:

```
[['1','3086703274'], ['1','3086703274'], ['1','3086703274',]]
```

How can I use pht of second element of every sublist in the list and compare it with list1[i][0]

Answer (score 1):

`if list1[i][0] in [val[1] for val in pht]:`

If `pht` is a fixed list then of course you are not going to calculate it in each loop but put `[val[1] for val in pht]` in a new list like pht_keys, thus:

```
pht_keys = [val[1] for val in pht]
for index, element in enumerate(list1):
    if element[0] in pht_keys:
        list_2_index = list2.index(index)
...
```

I discourage the use of

```
for i in range(len(list1)):
   print(f'element index {i} is {list1[i]}')
```

Do it the pythonic way with enumerate if you need the index

```
for index, element in enumerate(list1):
   print(f'element index {index} is {element}')
```